# JS Form not submitting

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm struggling with this form that refuse to work. Hitting the submit button nothing happens.
There is an addEventListener that should do the job, but it just check the input fields without send the infos (there is no back-end, data is sent via FormSubmit.com).
Basically inside the addEventListener function there is a subfunction that checks if the data is correct or not, changing the element class in color & icon according to the result (green/red).

```js
const form = document.getElementById('form');
const name = document.getElementById('name');
const email = document.getElementById('email');
const phone = document.getElementById('phone');
const message = document.getElementById('message');


form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  checkInputs();
});


function checkInputs() {
  //get values from inputs
  const nameValue = name.value.trim();
  const emailValue = email.value.trim();
  const phoneValue = phone.value.trim();
  const messageValue = message.value;

  if (nameValue === '') {
    //show error
    //add error class
    setErrorFor(name, 'Name field cannot be blank');
  } else {
      //add success class
      setSuccessFor(name);
  };

  if (emailValue === '') {
    setErrorFor(email, 'Email field cannot be blank');
  } else if (!isEmail(emailValue)) {
      setErrorFor(email, 'Invalid Email')
  } else {
      setSuccessFor(email);
  };

  if (phoneValue === '') {
    setErrorFor(phone, 'Phone number field cannot be blank');
  } else if (!isPhone(phoneValue)) {
      setErrorFor(phone, 'Invalid Phone Number')
  } else {
      setSuccessFor(phone);
  };

  if (messageValue === '') {
    setErrorFor(message, 'Message field cannot be blank');
  } else {
      setSuccessFor(message);
  };

};


function setErrorFor(input, message) {
  const formControl = input.parentElement; //.form-control
  const small = formControl.querySelector('small');

  //add error message inside small
  small.innerText = message;

  //add error class
  formControl.className = 'form-control error';
};


function setSuccessFor(input) {
  const formControl = input.parentElement;
  formControl.className = 'form-control success';
};


function isEmail(email) {
  return /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/.test(email);
};


function isPhone(phone) {
  return /^[\+]?[(]?[0-9]{3}[)]?[-\s\.]?[0-9]{3}[-\s\.]?[0-9]{4,6}$/im.test(phone);
};
```

```html
<form target="_blank" action="https://formsubmit.co/myemail@gmail.com" method="POST" id="form">

  <input type="hidden" name="_subject" value="New submission">

  <div class="form-control" id="form-control">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" id="name">
  </div>

  <div class="form-control" id="form-control">
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" id="email">
  </div>

  <div class="form-control" id="form-control">
    <input type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" id="phone">
  </div>

  <div class="form-control" id="form-control">
    <textarea name="message" rows="4" placeholder="Type your message here...." id="message"></textarea>
  </div>

  <button type="submit">SEND</button>

</form>
```

Comment: You're preventing the default behavior of from submission with your event listener, so you need to submit manually after calling `checkInputs()`. See some examples [here](https://formsubmit.co/ajax-documentation)

Comment: Guess what? It worked just adding form.submit() after calling checkInputs() as you suggested. Thank you so much man!